# Syntax error, multiple markers at line

Tags: android, syntax-error, android-camera

```
ImageView ivCamera;

FlashLightControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
ivCamera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);
```

`Syntax error on token ";" ,, expected.`

---

```
- Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ")", { expected after    this token
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete       FieldDeclaration
- Syntax error on token ".", ... expected
- Return type for the method is missing
```

---

`Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody`

Comment: This is a site for questions and answers, so you should probably start by making sure there's a question mark present in your "question".

Comment: Missing variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your FlashLightControl variable:

```
FlashLightControl flc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
ivCamera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);
```

And on another note, is a `Button` able to be treated as a `FlashLightControl` instance?

Maybe you want

```
Button flashLightControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
```

Comment: You're right, dude) I thought I can first declare variables "Button flc;" And then assign values ​​to them "flc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);"

Comment: You can *declare* a variable without *initializing* it, which is how you describe: "Button flc;"  However, 'flc' will be null until you explicitly *initialize* it with "flc = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing an object reference. Please change the following line of code from:

```
FlashLightControl = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
```

To this:

```
FlashLightControl flashControlName = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flashcontrol);
```

This however will only work if the the `FlashLightControl` is of the type `Button` or compatible with it.

Hope this helps.